# shell script to insert lines in httpd.conf files

Tags: apache, shell, httpd.conf

I want to disable `Put` method in `httpd.conf` file using shell script.

We need to check the conf file if we have below block, if we do not have one, we need add one like below it:

```
<Location />
  <LimitExcept GET DELETE POST OPTIONS HEAD>
    Deny from all
    Order deny,allow
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I tried a couple scenarios but it did not work out.

Shell script:

```
if grep -q 'LimitExcept GET DELETE POST OPTIONS HEAD' "/home/sgorip1/scripts/test.conf";
then
    echo "PUT Method already existed"
else
    sed -i '/ErrorLog /i \
    <Location /> \
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS HEAD> \
            Deny from all \
            Order deny,allow \
        <LimitExcept> \
    </Location>' /home/sgorip1/scripts/test.conf
fi
```

But it is adding the above lines append to ErrorLog.

Comment: if grep -q 'LimitExcept GET DELETE POST OPTIONS HEAD' "/home/sgorip1/scripts/test.conf";
then
echo "PUT Method already existed"
else
sed -i '/ErrorLog /i \
<Location /> \
  <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS HEAD> \
    Deny from all \
    Order deny,allow \
   <LimitExcept> \
</Location>' /home/sgorip1/scripts/test.conf
fi

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting a question, make sure you edit it using code sections (`{}`).  I did it for this first post.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] before posting another question.